# IE not storing $_SESSION variables properly, works in mozilla however

Tags: php, internet-explorer, session, loops, session-variables

This problem is only in IE. Mozilla and chrome work fine, it's very hard to target where I am going wrong.

I have a for loop building a multiple level $_SESSION var for example:

```
$seq = 1;
for($d=1; $d<=10; $d++){

    if($_POST["COMPANY_$d"] && $_POST["PHONE_$d"]){
        $_SESSION['c'][$seq]["COMPANY"] = $_POST["COMPANY_$d"];
        $_SESSION['c'][$seq]["PHONE"] = $_POST["PHONE_$d"];
        if($_POST["COUNTRY_$d"] == 'Canada'){
            $_SESSION['c'][$seq]["STATE"] = $_POST["STATE_$d"];
        }else{
            $_SESSION['c'][$seq]["STATE"] = $_POST["STATE_2_$d"];
        }
        $_SESSION['c'][$seq]["COUNTRY"] = $_POST["COUNTRY_$d"];
        $_SESSION['c'][$seq]["ADDY1"] = $_POST["ADDY1_$d"];
        $_SESSION['c'][$seq]["ADDY2"] = $_POST["ADDY2_$d"];
        $_SESSION['c'][$seq]["CITY"] = $_POST["CITY_$d"];
        $_SESSION['c'][$seq]["ZIP"] = $_POST["ZIP_$d"];

        $seq++;
    }//end declare var in $_SESSION

}//end for
```

When I print_r($_SESSION) in mozilla I get the proper values, but in IE all I get is:

```
Array
(
    [c] => 11
)
```

I'm not sure if the 11 is from my loop or other code somewhere. I've spent 3 hours now going through the code with a fine tooth comb and can't find anything that's interfering. This works in Mozilla, what is up with IE? What is my problem?

Comment: Does your php configured to use cookies for storing `$_SESSION`? By default they are stored internally and never leave web-server.

Comment: This is quite strange. Sessions should not be affected by browsers, they are managed server-side. Try to clear your IE cache and cookies list. Do the same on Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cookies disabled in IE then PHP will attempt to append the session ID to the URL so that it may connect the session to your browser.  If your application is inadvertently clearing the session ID from the URL either from your code or if you have any commands setup via .htaccess then that could be the problem.  I'd first check your IE browser and make sure it is not disabling cookies to verify that is the problem.